# Finding a permutation matrix that preserves a property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\pi$ be a $1\times n$ matrix with $\pi_i>0$ and $\sum_i \pi_i=1$. Let $P$ be a probability matrix (of size $n\times n$) i.e. $P_{ij}\geq 0$ and $\sum_j P_{ij}=1$. Also, let $\pi P=\pi$ and $P$ be invertible.

> I am trying to check if there exists some permutation matrix (of size $n\times n$) $\Pi$, other than the identity matrix, s.t. $\pi \Pi P = \pi$ for arbitrary $\pi, P$ that satisfy $\pi P=\pi$.

My attempt: If $\pi_i=\pi_j$ for all $i,j$, then for any permutation matrix $\Pi$, we have $\pi \Pi P=\pi P=\pi$. But for arbitrary $\pi,P$  there does not exist a $\Pi$ s.t. $\pi\Pi=\pi$. But if there did exist such a $\Pi$, we can say $\pi\Pi P=\pi P=\pi$. The reason why $\Pi$ does not exist for arbitrary $\pi$ is: Let us say we look at a $\pi$ s.t. $\pi_i\neq \pi_j$ for all $i\neq j$, then for any permutation matrix $\Pi$, $\pi\Pi\neq \pi$. So in order to find $\Pi$ s.t. $\pi \Pi P=\pi$, we can say $\pi \Pi=\pi P^{-1}$.

So my question is: Can we find a $\Pi$ for arbitrary $\pi, P$ which satisfy $\pi P=\pi$?

Comment: As long as $P$ is invertible, this is equivalent to the assumption $\pi \Pi = \pi$, so you can safely ignore $P$.  The question is then "does there exist some $\Pi$ such that $\pi\Pi = \pi$ for arbitrary $\pi >0$.  Only $\Pi=I$ does so.

Comment: No, there is no $\Pi$ that works for all $\pi,P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In general, no such $\Pi$ will exist.

For example, consider
$$
P = \frac 14\pmatrix{3&1\\2&2}, \quad \pi = (2/3,1/3).
$$
There is only one permutation matrix $\Pi$ of size $2$ such that is not equal to the identity. Verify that for this matrix $\Pi$, $\pi \Pi P \neq \pi$.